# Spire.net Excel to PDF Conversion with Barcode Font

Tags: azure-web-app-service, spire.xls

We are using Spire.Xls library to Convert Excel files to PDF after some transformation.
Things were working fine until we upgraded Spire to latest version.

The document is generated fine, but it doesn't renders Barcode font which we have specified in the Excel Template. It shows numeric digits instead.

We are hosting application in Azure App service, so we can't install those Fonts there.
After going through latest guidelines, it appears that the framework has new approach to embed private fonts to the excel, However it seems like there is some issue related to Font caching.
After adding custom fonts, the barcode appears in the generated PDF. However, it appears only for the first request. All subsequent requests after first request are not loading the document with correct barcode. It shows plain numeric number instead.

Here is the code snippet we tried based on latest documentation.

```
var fontPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelDocuments/idautomationhc39m_free_version.ttf");
Workbook document = new Workbook();
var fontArr = new string[] { fontPath };
document.CustomFontFilePaths = fontArr;
var res = document.GetCustomFontParsedResult();

document.LoadFromFile(template);
//Further processing

document.SaveToFile("d:\\test.pdf", Spire.Xls.FileFormat.PDF);
```

Does any one had same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for `COMMUNITY EXPERT` ryanchill's answer.

> App Services are [sandboxes](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) and [certain workflows](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks) therefore aren't supported such as PDF generation. To get around this issue, you can deploy your app as a [docker container image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-windows) with the fonts you need installed on it.

---

*Due to App services are PaaS services, they cannot be supported when it comes to relying on third-party application support (such as Microsoft Office) or system-level (fonts, etc.).*

**Related Posts:**

[How to upload custom fonts to Azure AppService and use them in the PDF reporting?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/132764/how-to-upload-custom-fonts-to-azure-appservice-and.html)

Comment: @json Thank you for the answer. Our code works perfectly fine on Azure app service using Spire.Net. The issue is that it only works for initial request. Subsequent requests sent to APIs doesn't return file with Barcode. It is something related to Spire Font caching i guess.